# Prove the inequality involving exponent and inverse sine

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $$4e^{\operatorname{asin}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}-3e^{\operatorname{asin}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)}-e^{\operatorname{asin}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}<0$$

I tried to rewrite it as $3\left(e^{\operatorname{asin}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}-e^{\operatorname{asin}\left(\frac{1}{9}\right)}\right)-\left(e^{\operatorname{asin}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}-e^{\operatorname{asin}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}\right)<0$ but without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\in (0,1)$, $$\frac{\mathrm{d} ^2 }{\mathrm{d} x^2}\;e^{\arcsin x}= \frac{(\sqrt{1-x^2}+x)e^{\arcsin x}}{(\sqrt{1-x^2})^3}>0$$

So, $e^{\arcsin x}$ is strictly convex for $x\in (0,1)$. Using Karamata's Majorization Inequality with

$$\left( \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6} \right ) \prec  \left( \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{9} \right)$$

We have

\begin{align*}3e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{9}}+e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{3}}&=e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{9}}+e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{9}}+e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{9}}+e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{3}} \\
&>e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{6}}+e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{6}}+e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{6}}+e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{6}}  \\
&= 4e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{6}}
\end{align*}

**easier way by VTand's comment**

By Jensen Inequality

\begin{align*}3e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{9}}+e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{3}}
&> 4e^{\arcsin (\frac{1/9+1/9+1/9+1/3}{4})}\\
&=4e^{\arcsin \frac{1}{6}}
\end{align*}

Comment: The less powerful [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) would also work in a similar manner.

Comment: @VTand exactly, also it is easier to understand, I will edit it, thank u.

Comment: I wonder how could we tag this question under `pre-calculus`??? Not only the OP has not shown his(her) efforts, but also he(she) has misled us!

Comment: @TahaDirek, why $\left( \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{6} \right ) \prec  \left( \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{9}, \frac{1}{3} \right)$?

Comment: @AndrewFount https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization

Comment: @TahaDirek, I saw that. The question is why $\frac{1}{6} \prec \frac{1}{9}$ if $\frac{1}{6} > \frac{1}{9}$?

Comment: @AndrewFount edited, now it is true, thank u

Comment: @TahaDirek, you're welcome!